# MacBook clamshell mode without Power Adapter does not work with the Amphetamine app

Tags: macos, battery, macbook, macbook-air, macos-monterey

I am using an MacBook Air M1 running macOS Monterey 12.2.1 (21D62) and when I tried to enable clamshell mode (without the power-adapter connected) with the Amphetamine app using this tutorial: https://beebom.com/use-macbook-clamshell-mode-without-power-adapter/

But it does not work. When I close the lid with the HDMI and keyboard and mouse connected, the external monitor stays black.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Best bet is to contact the developer directly. Their [GitHub repo is here](https://github.com/x74353).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was totally easy:
I forgot to start a new session in amphetamine.

Comment: This is not working for me on M1 pro 2021 model on MacOS Monterey 12.5. I have an indefinite session running and music playing on spotify. When I close the lid the music keeps playing, so far so good. Then when I plugin my monitor HDMI input the music stops and my monitor does not show anything. It reports no signal and it remain black.

Comment: I got this working by additionally running these commands ```sudo pmset -a sleep 0
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1```

Answer (score 1):

Terminate the last session with Right Button and start a new one.
It works fine on Macbook Pro M1 PRO 14" 2022.

Comment: This is not working for me on M1 pro 2021 model on MacOS Monterey 12.5. I have an indefinite session running and music playing on spotify. When I close the lid the music keeps playing, so far so good. Then when I plugin my monitor HDMI input the music stops and my monitor does not show anything. It reports no signal and it remain black.

Comment: I got this working by additionally running these commands ```sudo pmset -a sleep 0
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1```

Comment: @GopiPalamalai did you tried to restart Amphetamine ? Re-Install Amphetamine?
Check some configurations of Amphetamine? 
Before to use CLI and pmset.

Comment: Yes I did all of those and it still did not help. I also figured I could just use `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1` and not use Amphetamine at all. Just setting that would disable sleep and there is no need for Amphetamine